# Golang protobuf dynamic messages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a go tcp client to receive events from a server. The server response are bytes structured in this way:

1. start byte
2. length byte
3. command byte
4. adress1 byte
5. adress2 byte
6. address3 byte
7. address4 byte
8. error byte
9. param 1 byte
   ...
   N. param N byte

Can I use Protobufs for this? If yes how should I structure the message?

Kind regards,
  Jurgen

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: yes, you can. And it must looks something like this:

proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Event {
  bytes start = 1;
  bytes length = 2;
  ...
  repeated bytes param = 9;
}
```

your go struct will be:

```
type Event struct {
    Start  []byte
    Length []byte
    ...
    Param  [][]byte
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. If the last byte is a checksum. Should it be part of the param? Or do you suggest another solution?